# See-through jelly like substance shader

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, shaders, transparency

I'm trying to recreate the little red balls on top of the gunkan sushi. So far I have this. Just a glass shader with a translucent shader added on top. I don't know if this makes any sense but if it doesn't please fill me in. Also ignore the rest of the render since it's obviously not final and just a test render.

Looking forward to your answers!

[image][image: Gunkan]

Comment: Probably worth looking at sub-surface scattering for both the roe and the cucumber.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I can make it reflective like the ones in the photo with SSS on?

Comment: I am not that experienced, but there are tutorials on the web (try BlenderGuru as an example) that can go through the basics. Even though you have accepted the answer below, a good learning exercise would be to compare SSS to the glass shader to see the visual differences (maybe even combining the two approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried SSS at first but was not happy with the results. I decided a glass shader looks much better.

I just used a Principled shader with transmission set to 1, for glass. Then I added some volume scatter with a slight orange color just so it doesn't look like glass and has some volume in the inside.

I did not do it here but I think slightly deforming the spheres will give it some more realism.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I never really looked at volume scatter this way. I'll try it as soon as I can.